# Install own python package in conda environment

Tags: python, pip, conda

I started to write my own python package and want to install this in my virtual conda environment. Now, I'm a little bit confused about the possibilities to do this.
In general, during my search I found these two commands to install my package:

1. `pip install -e <my_package>`
2. `conda-develop .`

Using the first method leads to the desired result and my package is listed, if `conda list` has been called (although the package is still not visible in the anaconda navigator, but anyway).
In contrast to this the second method only returned *"completed operation for: <path_to_my_package>"*, but didn't install the packe in my environment.

Does anyone know what this could be or what I am doing wrong? As far as I know, there is also the possibility to create packages directly in conda. Is there any advantage for, if it's only a private package for me?

Thank's a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you write a Conda recipe for your package? `conda develop` is for installing *Conda* packages while still developing locally. Maybe have a look at [conda-build docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank's for the link and clarification. I only have a classical setup.py file. Is there any advantage for me to create a conda package?

Comment: The documentation will probably best answer that for you. Kinda depends on your project. For pure Python package, I'd just do `pip install -e`. If you plan to publish to PyPI, I'd do that first, and then you can script Conda Forge to auto-generate Conda packages from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is the case. When you have a conda environment set up. The packages in the conda will be considered as global package. So, if a package is installed in your conda environment and you choose the conda interpreter in your vent environment, that package will be available. And based on your question, what you want is to be able to install a package that is only available in this vent environment. In this case, you can use terminal to go to your project path. And then use the normal `pip install` , in this way that package will be in the vent environment only.

> Issues may arise when using pip and conda together. When combining
> conda and pip, it is best to use an isolated conda environment. Only
> after conda has been used to install as many packages as possible
> should pip be used to install any remaining software. If modifications
> are needed to the environment, it is best to create a new environment
> rather than running conda after pip. When appropriate, conda and pip
> requirements should be stored in text files.
>
> Use pip only after conda Install as many requirements as possible with
> conda then use pip.
>
> Pip should be run with --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed (the
> default).
>
> Do not use pip with the --user argument, avoid all users installs.

And [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env) is the official guild about using conda with pip.

Comment: If the local package is pure Python (no compiled code, wheels, etc.) and all the dependencies are already installed (preferably through Conda), then installing through `pip install -e` is not problematic.